# Javassist: javassist.CannotCompileException: by java.lang.ClassFormatError: Duplicate method name&signature in class file

Tags: java, eclipse, runtime-error, javassist

I am using javassist to change a method body. I can do that when the method is defined in the application. However, when I want to change a method defined in a jar file used by the application then I get the below run time error:

```
javassist.CannotCompileException: by java.lang.ClassFormatError: Duplicate method name&signature in class file pk1/StringBuilder.
```

The below code is used to change a method body. I am using eclipse IDE. The error happens when **clas.toClass();** is called.

```
public class JassistTiming {

public static void main(String[] arg) {

    //first parameter is name of class, and the second one is name of method
    String[] argv = {"pk1.StringBuilder","buildString"};

    // start by getting the class file and method
    CtClass clas = ClassPool.getDefault().get(argv[0]);

    // add timing interceptor to the class
    addTiming(clas, argv[1]);
    clas.writeFile();
    System.out.println("Added timing to method " + argv[0] + "." + argv[1]);

    clas.toClass(); //Run time error happens here                                             
}

private static void addTiming(CtClass clas, String mname) throws NotFoundException, CannotCompileException {

    CtMethod mold = clas.getDeclaredMethod(mname);

    String nname = mname+"$impl";
    mold.setName(nname);
    CtMethod mnew = CtNewMethod.copy(mold, mname, clas, null);

    String type = mold.getReturnType().getName();
    StringBuffer body = new StringBuffer();
    body.append("{\nlong start = System.currentTimeMillis();\n");
    if (!"void".equals(type)) {
        body.append(type + " result = ");
    }
    body.append(nname + "($$);\n");

    body.append("System.out.println(\"Call to method " + mname +
        " took \" +\n (System.currentTimeMillis()-start) + " +
        "\" ms.\");\n");
    if (!"void".equals(type)) {
        body.append("return result;\n");
    }
    body.append("}");

    mnew.setBody(body.toString());
    clas.addMethod(mnew);
}
}
```

Update: Code for StringBuilder:

```
public class StringBuilder { 

public String buildString(int length) { 

    String result = ""; 

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) { 
        result += (char)(i%26 + 'a'); 
    } 

    return result; 
}
```

Comment: Show the code of the class pk1.StringBuilder

Comment: The question is updated with code for pk1.StringBuilder

Comment: pk1 is the package`? Perhaps there is another class "StringBuilder"? Please rename your class and try again

Comment: Could you please add how do you call `JassistTiming`. A quick test with `java -cp javassist-3.7.ga.jar:foobar.jar:. JassistTiming` was successful. (foobar.jar contains the class pk1.StringBuilder).

Comment: I found the problem. It is a problem when I run the program in Eclispe. More comment below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found the reason.

Assuming that `foobar.jar` contains the class `pk1.StringBuilder`

Following is working

```
java -cp javassist-3.7.ga.jar:foobar.jar:. JassistTiming 
java -cp javassist-3.7.ga.jar:foobar.jar:. JassistTiming
```

The instrumented class `StringBuilder.class` is stored in the subdirectory `pk1` and the instrumented method is called.

The following is working too

```
java -cp javassist-3.7.ga.jar:.:foobar.jar JassistTiming
```

but fail on the second execution, because the class `StringBuilder.class` is now first found in the subdirectory `pk1` which is the already instrumented class, so the method `public void buildString$impl()` already exists in this class.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. In the first run the program works fine, and a new class file for **StringBuilder** is created. However, in the next runs, the Eclipse does not overwrite this class and I get the above run time error. If I delete this class file manually then the program works fine for the next run.

I create a jar file from the application and run that in command line and it works fine. So, the problem is with Eclipse that cannot overwrite the created class file.